# Both true and false got from checkbox if it is checked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, checkbox

In my `MVC` view I have a `form` with method `GET`. In that form I have several fields which works fine. After adding a `checkbox` I found strange behavior. If that `checkbox` is unchecked I have `myCheckbox=false` in `GET` parameter, but when I check the `checkbox` I have `myCheckbox=true&myCheckbox=false`.

My view:

```
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Get)) { 
<fieldset>
    SomeInput: @Html.TextBox("someInput") <br />
    ...
    MyCheckbox: @Html.CheckBox("myCheckbox") <br />
</fieldset>
}
...
```

With value `data` in `SomeInput` and unchecked `checkbox` I'm getting url:

`...?someInput=data&myCheckbox=false`

and with checked `checkbox` I'm getting:

`...?someInput=data&myCheckbox=true&myCheckbox=false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal behaviour.

Standard html forms do not send a checkbox unless it is checked. This would lead to a missing parameter in your querystring if the box is not checked.

The html helper generates an `input type=hidden` for each `input type=checkbox` that you ask for (and you would have noted this if you took a little time to check the generated html). This is done to ensure that the field is passed down whether it is checked or not. So in the "not checked" scenario the actual checkbox is ignored, and you only have the value from the hidden field:

```
myField=false
```

If the checkbox is checked both are passed down, with the same name:

```
myField=true&myField=false
```

If I remember correctly if you declare in the receiving actionmethod a parameters `bool myField` the default ModelBinder takes care of this particular scenario and will net you `true` when the checkbox is checked and `false` when it is not.